# How to backup all e-mails on an Ubuntu VPS?

Tags: server, backup, email

Going to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch, because it got infected. Now I want to backup all the e-mails and restore them after reinstall. I am having 4 e-mails of type `something@domain.com`. I can see the files in `/var/mail/`, but they seem to be too small to only copy those files, since there were hundreds of e-mails with PDF's included and files are having ~4mb.

How can I backup and later restore all the e-mails, so no data is lost? My server was set to receive/send e-mails by `postfix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Inbox is by default stored in `/var/mail`, whilst any sub-folders is stored in `~/mail/` per user.

Taking a backup of `/home` is a good practice anyway.